# Family of circles touching a line

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I found this in a book but I am not able to understand how they got this result. It goes the equation family of circles touching a given line $(y-y_1)=m(x-x_1)$ at $(x_1,y_1)$ for any value of $m$ is 
$(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + \lambda[(y-y_1) - m(x-x_1)] = 0$ where $\lambda$ is the parameter

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The equation family of circles you quote is not an equation, because the "=" sign is missing.

Comment: Sorry, it's equal to zero

Comment: Are you sure of the wording? If the line is a "given" line, then m, the slope of that line must be fixed and hence CANNOT be ‘for any value of m’.